# Nodejs | Exhange Data Between Controllers

Tags: node.js, angular, promise, async-await

> I have my PlantsController where I get the Plants like this:

```
function getAll() {
  const plants= HttpRequestPromise.get(config.ApiURL+'allPlants', config.head);
  return plants;
}

export class PlantsController {
  ...
  public getPlants() {
    return async (req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction): Promise<Response> => {
      try {
        const plants = await getAll();
        return res
          .status(OK)
          .send(plants);
      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    };
  }
  ...
}
export default new PlantsController();
```

> I have PlantedActivitiesController where I get the PlantedActivities
>   like this:

```
import plantsController from '../plants/plants.controller';
export class PlantedActivitiesController {
  ...
  public getPlantedActivities(){
    return async (req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction): Promise<Response> => {
      try {


        var plants = ?  // How can i get the plants from PlantsController?
                        // plantsController.get...?

        ...


      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

*So, how can I get the plants to my PlantedActivitiesController?*

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

I created a getPlantsHelper like this:

```
function getAll() {
  const plants= HttpRequestPromise.get(config.ApiURL+'allPlants', config.head);
  return plants;
}
export class PlantsController {
  ...

  //-----------
  public getPlantsHelper(){
    return getAll()
  }
  //-----------

  public getPlants() {
    return async (req: Request, res: Response, next?: NextFunction): Promise<Response> => {
      try {
        const plants = await getAll();
        return res
          .status(OK)
          .send(plants);
      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    };
  }
  ...
}
```

and then in PlantedActivities I did:

```
activeSeeds = await plantsController.getPlantsHelper();
```